# For Kant, why is the Cogito an analytical proposition?

Tags: kant

Could someone please explain to me why is that Kant thinks of the *Cogito* as an analytical proposition? Is it only because the predicate of the *Cogito* is already presumed in the concept of an thinking subject? Or is there a more complex argument for it?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Yes; the **I** is “a single thing that cannot be resolved into a plurality of subjects, and hence a logically simple subject” (B407). Thus we have the numerical identity of the self as the thinking subject. According to Kant, this proposition is analytic: “this principle of the necessary unity of apperception is, to be sure, itself identical, thus an analytic proposition” (B135).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, is it also correct to say that, since it is reached by introspection, for Descartes, the Cogito is not an analytical proposition, but a synthetical one (to use a kantian terminology), that is, in Descartes point of view, does the predicate of existence in the Cogito requires some sort of experience - even if it is an interior one - to be known? Or does he shares Kant's point of view on this topic?

Comment: The concept of "analytic prop" is foreign to D... But yes, the *Cogito* is a sort of intuition, i.e. an "inner experience" and not only an "analysis" of words (or thoughts).

Answer (score 0):

It is an analytic proposition because it expresses analytically the simple unity of consciousness that is already presupposed by any thought as a synthetic unity. Abstracting from any further content, which constitutes an analysis, we find in every cognition this "I think", which denotes simply that various representations are unified under one consciousness. But this "I think", an analytic mark of the synthetic unity, of course doesn't constitute this very possibility (of an unified consciousness), as it would be truly hopeless to derive this prior sense of "I" from the fact that we think all of *our* representations alongside the "I think" - this already presupposes what Kant calls the *a priori* synthetic unity of consciousness. The "I think" only makes explicit the unity of consciousness.